# How do I open python 2.7 files in Pyscripter 2.5.3.0

Tags: python, pyscripter

My version of Pyscripter (Pyscripter 2.5.3.0) is working with python 3 code but not python 2 code. How do I make it work with python 2 code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"not working"*?

Comment: Is using [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) an option?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it thinks it is a python 3 file and has errors

Comment: How is it supposed to know that it isn't? 2.x and 3.x have the same extension. Doesn't PyScripter give you multiple different python version options in the Start menu?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not that I can see. I thought there would be a version of pyscripter for python 2 and a version for python 3. But I cannot find the version for python 2.

Comment: Which versions of python do you have installed?